# Initialize boost array/multi_array

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, initialization

I've defined `boost::(multi_)array`  with

```
typedef boost::multi_array<unsigned int, 1>  uint_1d_vec_t;
typedef boost::multi_array<unsigned int, 2>  uint_2d_vec_t;

uint_1d_vec_t    foo( boost::extents[ num_elements   ]          );
uint_2d_vec_t    boo( boost::extents[ num_elements/2 ][ kappa ] );
```

were `num_elements/2` ist an integer and `kappa` is a double, but contains only integer numbers (for example 79).

How do can I initialize `foo` and `boo` to `0`, when the number of elements in side them is known only at runtime?

Comment: @Octavian: Thanks, but adding tags into titles is the opposite of cleanup.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That seems to be a matter of personal point of view. [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title).

Comment: @OctavianDamiean: The prevailing view on that very thread is that tags in titles are bad. We already have a consistent, indexed tagging system. Mods have also backed me up on such edits in the past. Can't please everyone, of course.

Answer (score 2):

changing line

```
  std::fill( boo.begin()->begin() , boo.end()->end() , 0);
```

to

```
  std::fill( boo.origin(), boo.origin() + boo.size(), 0 );
```

solved my problem

Comment: You may want to use `boo.data()` instead.

Comment: Also might want to use `boo.num_elements()` instead of `boo.size()`.

Comment: From the documentation for `.size()` _This returns the number of values contained in a. It is equivalent to a.shape()[0];_ Agree with @wedesoft that you should use `.num_elements()`

Answer (score 0):

You may also wish to use calloc and then wrap the returned memory with a boost::multi_array_ref.

Answer (score -1):

```
uint_1d_vec_t    foo( boost::extents[ static_cast< uint_1d_vec_t::index >( num_elements   ) ]          );
uint_2d_vec_t    boo( boost::extents[ static_cast< uint_2d_vec_t::index >( num_elements/2 ) ][ static_cast< uint_2d_vec_t::index >( kappa ) ] );
```

Comment: sorry, but i dont understard where do i define in this solution the initialize value?

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score -3):

i used

```
std::fill( foo.begin() , foo.end()    , 0);
```

to solve my problem (don't know if it is better then boost::assign, since i was unable to apply it).

with `boo` i still have problem, since
    std::fill( boo.begin()->begin() , boo.end()->end() , 0);
pass compilation, but once i run my program, i get the following error:

> /usr/include/boost/multi_array/base.hpp:178: Reference boost::detail::multi_array::value_accessor_one::access(boost::type, boost::multi_array_types::index, TPtr, const boost::multi_array_types::size_type*, const boost::multi_array_types::index*, const boost::multi_array_types::index*) const [with Reference = unsigned int&, TPtr = unsigned int*, T = unsigned int]: Assertion `size_type(idx - index_bases[0]) < extents[0]' failed.Blockquote

here is a short code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
#include <iostream>

namespace vec {
   typedef boost::multi_array<unsigned int, 1>  uint_1d_vec_t;
   typedef boost::multi_array<unsigned int, 2>  uint_2d_vec_t;
   typedef uint_1d_vec_t::index                 index_1d_t;
   typedef uint_2d_vec_t::index                 index_2d_t;
}

using namespace std;

int main( ) { 

   unsigned int num_elements, num_bits, max_runs, m;
   num_bits = 12;
   max_runs = 5000;
   m        = 2;

   num_elements = ( 1 << num_bits );

   double kappa = 79;

   vec::uint_1d_vec_t    foo( boost::extents[ static_cast< vec::index_1d_t >(num_elements) ]                                          );
   vec::uint_2d_vec_t    boo( boost::extents[ static_cast< vec::index_2d_t >(num_elements) ][ static_cast< vec::index_2d_t >(kappa) ] );

   std::fill( foo.begin()          , foo.end()        , 0);
   std::fill( boo.begin()->begin() , boo.end()->end() , 0);

   std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of adding answers that do not answer the question.